# communication not allowed through windows firewall

Tags: windows, tcp, ftp, firewall, ports

I am trying to run ftp client and server.
The connection successful only if both server and client windows firewall is turned off.
I tried to turn the firewall on and allow roll for: 
 1. (inbound and outbound) tcp port 20-21  allow
 2. allow end point communication for server-client

However, my problem still not solved.
Anyone has any other ideas?

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. The server throw an exception. I found it when i created log file on both server and client side